# How does Phasing work with Phyrexian Unlife?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have the card [Phyrexian Unlife](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPhyrexian%20Unlife%5d) on the battlefield, and I have less than 0 life. If I cast [Teferi's Protection](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%27s%5d%2b%5bProtection%5d), what happens? Do I lose the game because Phyrexian Unlife is phased out? Or does it still keep me alive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have zero or less life, a phased out Phyrexian Unlife will not save you from losing the game. Under [the rules for Phasing](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Phasing), rule 702.25b says

> If a permanent phases out, its status changes to "phased out." Except for rules and effects that specifically mention phased-out permanents, a phased-out permanent is treated as though it does not exist. **It can't affect or be affected by anything else in the game.** A permanent that phases out is removed from combat. (See rule 506.4.)

Since the phased-out Phyrexian Unlife can't affect anything else in the game, that means it can't affect whether you lose the game from having 0 or less life.

Comment: Aright, interesting. That is definitely something to consider.